# Why is Share Button Unavailable in Ubuntu One?

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-one

[image]So, My that file is already uploaded and is in Ubuntu one folder but share button in right click context menu is unavailable. please help what to do

Comment: You should [report this as a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Add all the possible details there. Thanks

Comment: @Seth There is a non expected behavior from the system. In my glossary at least it means *bug*.

Comment: @Lucio On a second look, you're right. Part of it is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is already shared. I'm not sure why `Stop Publishing` or `Copy Web Link` are appearing disabled in that screen shot though. The `Share…` option there was only available for folders, not files.

Though the menu is appearing disabled, you may be able to click on `Copy Web Link` still. If so, it will put the URL for the file so you can give it to others, into your clipboard. You will be able to paste it into other applications. If you are unable to click on the menu item, then you are seeing an issue very similar to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client-gnome/+bug/987506 .